# Jenkins Maven Project Build shell not available

Tags: maven, jenkins, windows-shell

In Jenkins, I am using choice parameters plugin to allow a user to select which suite they would like to run. The problem I'm having is when I try to alter the option chosen in the parameter section to append the directory and .xml prefix the job fails. If I put the full name in the parameter and input it directly as a build data it works fine. Below is my jenkins setup, pom and error.

**Choice parameter data**

```
Name    choice
Choices CopyFunctionality
        CopyToFunctionality
```

**Window batch shell command**

```
@echo off

set SUITE=%choice%.xml

echo %SUITE%
```

**Build values**

```
clean test -PParameterisedBuild -DsuiteXmlFile=${SUITE}
```

**POM profile**

```
<profile>
            <id>ParameterisedBuild</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testNG XML Files\${SUITE}</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

**Maven error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Expert_Models: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file C:\Automation Framework\Jenkins\workspace\regression_tests_selectable\testNG XML Files\${SUITE} is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Automation Framework\Jenkins\workspace\regression_tests_selectable\pom.xml to com.ExpertModels/Expert_Models/0.1-SNAPSHOT/Expert_Models-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Exclude suiteXmlFiles param from POM, there is no need to have this param since your system params would override it.
2. You don't need to set jenkins params using batch script, jenkins will parse params for you.
3. Pass suite params to maven surefire plugin like:

   clean test -PParameterisedBuild -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=${choice(or whatever the name of your choice param is)}

P.S. Also I would recommend re-evaluate usage of profiles based on the info above, I'm pretty sure that in 99% of cases you could simply avoid having profiles.